# How to ECHO the angle bracket > from within a batch file creating another batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@ECHO OFF
echo echo 10.199.64.67 http://www.google.com >> C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt >> GoogleDNSPoison.bat
pause >nul
```

How to `echo` the angle bracket `>` into a text file being another batch file without using quotes `"` or any other form of text aligner?

Comment: Use caret to escape special symbols :  `^>`

Comment: `@(Echo @(Echo 10.199.64.67 google.com^) 1^>^> "%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS") 1>> "GoogleDNSPoison.bat" & Pause` would be my recommended one liner, _Note I've changed the filename to the correct one, used a domain name, without a protocol or subdomain, and protected from trailing spaces, using parentheses, (where the nested closing parentheses also need escaping with carets)_. You could also delay the automatic variable expansion, by dong it like this too: `@(Echo @(Echo 10.199.64.67 google.com^) 1^>^> "%%SystemRoot%%\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS") 1>> "GoogleDNSPoison.bat" & Pause`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As he mentioned @npocmaka , you should escape it with the Caret `^>`:

```
echo echo 10.199.64.67 http://www.google.com ^>^> C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt >> GoogleDNSPoison.bat
```

Further Reading about : [How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: The space left to `^>^>` and also the space left to `>>` should be removed to create the batch file without a space left to `>>` and a trailing space at end of the command line which on execution writes the IPv4 address and the host name without two trailing spaces into the file `hosts.txt`.